# If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, does $E[Y|X=x]$ depend on $x$.

Tags: probability

A penny and dime are tossed. Let $X$ denote the number of heads up. Then the penny is tossed again. Let $Y$ denote the number of heads up on the dime (from the first toss) and the penny from the second toss.

(a) Find the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=1$.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
x/y & 0& 1 & 2& f_x(x)\\
\hline
\\ 0 & 1/8 & 0 & 0 &1/8
\\ 1&1/8& 2/8& 0 & 3/8
\\ 2&0&2/8&1/8&3/8
\\ 3 & 0 & 0 & 1/8 & 1/8
\\
\hline
\\ f_y(y) & 2/8 & 4/8 & 2/8
\end{array}
$$
$ P(Y=y|X=1) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} \frac{P(X=1,Y=0)}{P(X=1)}=\frac{1}{3} & \mbox{for}y=0
\\ \frac{P(X=1,Y=1)}{P(X=1)}=\frac{2}{3} & \mbox{ for }y=1
\\ \frac{P(X=1,Y=2)}{P(X=1)}=0 & \mbox{ for }y=2
\end{matrix}\right. $

(b) Find the covariance on $X$ and $Y$

$E(XY)=(1)(1)\frac{2}{8}+(2)(1)\frac{2}{8}+(2)(2)\frac{1}{8}+(3)(2)\frac{1}{8}=2$

$E(X)=(1)\frac{4}{8}+(2)\frac{2}{8}=1$

$E(Y)=(1)\frac{3}{8}+(2)\frac{3}{8}+(3)\frac{1}{8}=\frac{12}{8}$

$cov[X,Y]=2-(1)(\frac{12}{8})=\frac{1}{2}$

(d) If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, does $E[Y|X=x]$ depend on $x$.

$E[Y|X=x] = \displaystyle\int_{y} y \displaystyle\frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}{f_{x}(x)} = \displaystyle\int_{y} y \displaystyle\frac{f_{x}(x)f_{y}(y)}{f_{x}(x)} = \displaystyle\int_{y} y f_{y}(y) = E[Y] $ then $E[Y|X=x]$ doesn't depend on $x$

Any suggestion or mistake? Thanks for your help :) have a nice day

Comment: Shouldn't both variables $X$ $Y$ take values on $\{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: @leonbloy       mmm no, because for example first penny (head) first dime (head) and finally the second penny (head) then $X=3$ because X denote the number of heads up and $Y=2$ because we (head up for the dime) and  (second head up for the second penny) I understand your point if X enote the number of heads up but only for the first and second toss you have the reason

Comment: So you understand that $X$ is the total number of heads, including  also the second penny? It's not clear for me.

Comment: @leonbloy        yes I understand this, but I think that you are right is just for the first penny and the first dime then (a) , (b) and (c) are wrong but, Is (d) right?